# How do I host .cur image cursor files?

Tags: image-hosting

I'm using a `.cur` file as an image cursor. I uploaded it to the only image host that I could find that accepts `.cur` files, but lately it doesn't properly load the cursor anymore.

My webhost now doesn't accept `.cur` files. I converted it to `.png` but those won't show in IE

Basically I'm looking for a way to host/upload a `.cur` file.

Comment: If you can upload to the server but not see it in the browser, maybe it's because your host does not associate the file extension with the correct mime type. A possible solution is adding one of this mime types: **image/x-win-bitmap** or **application/x-win-bitmap** to the **.cur** extension trough .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Have you asked your webhost to accept them?  It could just be that by default their uploaders will not accept .cur (it isn't a file extension I would think to allow) but if you asked nicely they would place it on the server for you.

The only other way I could think to do it is if you are able to rename files after upload to your host, then upload it as a .png and rename it to .cur when you are uploaded.  It is a nasty work around but it might work.

Uploading it to a third party is going to introduce other issues.